# Python not printing all element.texts when in a loop

Tags: python, selenium

Please help. I'm locating, printing and saving the printed element.text to a csv file. Something isn't right. Basically if I just print the element without click to a new page, all elements from the specified positions of the xpath will get output,see code below.

```
while True:
with open('C:/Python34/email.csv','a') as f:
    z=csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t',lineterminator = '\n',)
    row = []
        for sub_list in (driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='wrapper']/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[position() = 1 or position() = 2 or position() = 3]")):
                print(sub_list.text,end=" ")
```

However, if I include clicks in the loop(see code in below) it will only print the element of one position only(e.g. div[1]). e.g. in the first iteration it will only print element in div[1], the next iteration will only print element in div[2] and so forth. Please enlighten me. With thanks

```
for sub_list in (driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='wrapper']/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[position() = 1 or position() = 2 or position() = 3]")):
                print(sub_list.text,end=" ")
                z.writerow(sub_list.text)
                WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="detail-pagination-next-btn"]/span')))
                WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="detail-pagination-next-btn"]')))
                WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'detail-pagination-next-btn')))
                WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'detail-pagination-next-btn')))
                WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "detail-company-selection")))
                time.sleep(5)
                c=driver.find_element_by_id('detail-pagination-next-btn')
                c.click()
                time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: What library are us using, i.e. where does `driver` come from?  What does `c.click()` do?

Comment: Sorry. No expertise about Selenium. Added a tag for it. That might help.

Comment: Hey @MikeMüller , I have modified the code, I'm using selenium, c.click() is just to click the element to navigate to the next page. I now able to capture element from each xpath position. However, it one element doesn't exist, the loop becomes infinite. Could you please enlighten me how I can fix this?
    https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d802374101ce8f453a6a